# VBA - For Loop throuth each rows cannot work (no change in my dataset)

Tags: vba, excel, foreach

I got a large Excel dataset to be cleansed, here I want to record a macro to automate one of the steps. Please have a look at the screenshot below, what I want to do is let the program move the description (if any) under the Name (Column C) to Column F of Row above. For example, cut value in `C3` and paste that to `F2`.

#### A screenshot of the dataset

[image: A screenshot of the dataset]

I use for each loop to loop through each rows, but nothing happens if I run my code. I use `countblank()` function to identify the rows that only include a description. Here is my code:

```
    Sub ForEach_Loop()

Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Set ws3 = Worksheets("Sheet3")

Dim CutCell As Integer
Dim PasteCell As Integer

CutCell = 2
PasteCell = 1

Dim Count_Blank As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range

Set rng = ws3.Range("A1:M300")

For Each row In rng.Rows

  Count_Blank = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(ws3.Range(ws3.Cells(1, CutCell),     ws3.Cells(13, CutCell)))
  If Count_Blank = 12 Then
      ws3.Range(ws3.Cells(3, CutCell)).Cut ws3.Range(ws3.Cells(6, PasteCell))
  End If
  CutCell = CutCell + 1
  PasteCell = PasteCell + 1
Next row

End Sub
```

I am quite new to VBA, but this work is really time-consuming, anyone can tell me what the problems are in my code?

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub ForEach_Loop()

    Dim ws3 As Worksheet
    Dim row As Range

    Set ws3 = Worksheets("Sheet3")

    For Each row In ws3.Range("A2:M300").Rows

      If Application.CountA(row) = 1 And row.Cells(3).Value <> "" Then

        With row.Cells(3)
            row.Cells(6).Offset(-1, 0).Value = .Value
            .ClearContents
        End With

      End If

    Next row

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! easy and efficient.